# UIScrollView: subview added but not showing up

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subviews

I have a UIScrollView called scroller. It has subviews which are custom UIButtons..I try to print the number of subviews before and after adding like as follows

```
    NSLog(@"Adding %d b4 %d",buttonno, [[self.scroller subviews] count]);
    [self.scroller addSubview:menuBtn];
    NSLog(@"Adding %d after %d",buttonno, self.scroller.subviews.count);
```

The subview is not showing up. But the number of subviews increments for example the output of this is like

> 2014-03-11 17:53:49.863 PC2[4519:60b] Adding 1 b4 10
>
> 2014-03-11 17:53:49.872 PC2[4519:60b] Adding 1 after 11

But when I try to print the number of subviews using a test button which runs the code

```
NSLog(@"Buttons subviews: %d",self.scroller.subviews.count);
```

I can see that no subview is added..I can also see that no subview is added when I see the variables in the debugger.

btw I'm adding buttons based on timer  `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(checkForTiles) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Update:: The code to add subview

```
                if (!alreadyExists)
{
    NSLog(@"Adding %d b4 %d",buttonno, [[self.scroller subviews] count]);
    //AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    pccButtonViewController *menuBtn=nil;
    menuBtn=[pccButtonViewController alloc ];
    menuBtn = [pccButtonViewController buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuBtn.no=buttonno;
    menuBtn.slotNo=buttonCount;
    menuBtn.frame = [[slotFrames objectAtIndex:menuBtn.slotNo] CGRectValue];
    [menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"L%02d_Tile.jpg",buttonno]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(miniButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    menuBtn.no=buttonno;
    menuBtn.alpha=0.0f;
    [self.scroller addSubview:menuBtn];
    NSLog(@"Adding %d after %d",buttonno, self.scroller.subviews.count);
    //NSLog(@"Subview Added %d btn no:%@",buttonno,[slotFrames objectAtIndex:menuBtn.slotNo]);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    //self.menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 10, 50, 60);
    menuBtn.alpha=1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [buttons addObject:menuBtn];
    buttonCount++;
}
buttonclicked=0;
[self.scroller  setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self.scroller  bounds].size.width,(ceil(buttonCount/tilesPerRow)+1)*[self.scroller  bounds].size.width/tilesPerRow/2*3)];
appdelegate.Sharevar.vidsyncButtons=self.scroller.subviews.copy;//Used to maintain State when the view is presented for the second time
```

**This works fine when the View runs for the first time.The problems arise when it is run for the second time..I remove the view from appdelegate like this**

```
-(void)removeAnyView
{
NSLog(@"Removing");
if (viewonScreen)
{
    viewonScreen=false;
    [self.inPort prepareToBeDeleted];
    self.inPort=Nil;
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{[self     presentView];}];
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you post code for adding views to your scroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time.. I forgot about this question.. The error was caused by **not invalidating the NSTimer**.. Got to be careful with these..

Answer (score 0):

Any updates to the UI have to be on the main thread, which your NSTimer won't be, so you need to do something like this...

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.scroller addSubview:menuBtn];
});
```

Comment: I'm doing like this in the function checkforTiles "[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addTile:)
                                               withObject:content waitUntilDone:YES];" Wouldn't this be enough??

Comment: I think you are going to have to post more code, so that people can see whats going on. At the moment there isn't enough to go on

Comment: Tried like what u suggested and the app hung..No response..It's stuck executing it..now errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
menuBtn=[pccButtonViewController alloc ];
```

to this

```
menuBtn=[[pccButtonViewController alloc ] init];
```

From documenation:

> buttonWithType:
>
> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects
> with specific configurations. If you subclass UIButton, this method
> does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an
> instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button
> directly.

Comment: Still the problem prevails